# Why are these AspNet Core Blazor claims different on client than on server?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, claims-based-identity

I am using Blazor 3.2.0 with Identity Authentication and Authorization.

When a user logs in, the following claims are created server side:

[image]

However, when the login processes finish, the following claims are available on the blazor client.

[image]

Notice, the managing-agent-id claim is not showing on the client. (This claim is loaded from the AspNetUserClaims table in Identity)

Comment: I guess your client does not request the scope sending this claims...